# How to describe someone destroyed physically and mentally?

Tags: synonyms, american-english, british-english

I want to know the best way to describe someone who was abused physically and mentally by the other person.

Ex:A woman got abused by her husband.

Comment: ... as opposed to just abused physically or just abused mentally? And not emotionally? Why not just someone who was abused in general? Your title also says "destroyed" not "abused." You need to provide more context, otherwise it's not clear exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Often in the media, they are referred to as "Victims of abuse", although there is a growing trend to rename this to "Survivors of abuse".

> ## [Victim or Survivor?](https://www.rainn.org/articles/key-terms-and-phrases)
>
> "One of the most frequent questions we receive is, “Should I use the term victim or survivor?” Both terms are applicable. RAINN tends to use the term “victim” when referring to someone who has recently been affected by sexual violence; when discussing a particular crime; or when referring to aspects of the criminal justice system.
> We often use “survivor” to refer to someone who has gone through the recovery process, or when discussing the short- or long-term effects of sexual violence.
> Some people identify as a victim, while others prefer the term survivor. The best way to be respectful is to ask for their preference."

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'tortured' to describe such a person.

From the Cambridge Dictionary:

> **Torture** (noun)
>
> > the act of causing great physical or mental pain in order to persuade someone to do something or to give information, or to be cruel to a person or animal

Comment: OP needs a noun that refers to person.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal No: a noun is not specified, and the adjective *tortured* fits the question.